# Convertir objeto a valor númerico

Tags: angular, typescript

comunidad, como puedo convertir un valor así (Es el único valor que recibo):

**{success: 194}**

a valor numérico: **194**.

lo recibo así y según yo lo convierto en objeto y ya luego pasarlo con Number() pero no me funciona.
**this.id_institucion = Object.values(v);**

en la v recibo el objeto {success: 194}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**`Object.values()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) te devuelve un arreglo, en donde el elemento del arreglo es el valor de dicho objeto. Para obtener solo ese elemento del arreglo (el valor obtenido), tendrías que utilizar el método [**`toString()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toString) para convertir al arreglo en una cadena tipo **`string`** y así solo obtendrás el valor como una cadena de texto:

```js
let obj = {success: 194}

let result = Object.values(obj).toString()

console.log(result)
console.log(typeof(result))
```

Y ahora lo que quieres es convertir el resultado a un valor numérico, fácilmente lo podrías volver a convertir al resultado de tipo **`string`** a tipo **`number`**, para esto utilizarías la función [**`Number()`**](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-number-function/?ref=lbp), por ejemplo:

```js
let obj = {success: 194}

let result = Object.values(obj).toString()
let numero = Number(result)

console.log(numero)
console.log(typeof(numero))
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias mi hermano, si me salio como requeria. te lo super agradezco.

Comment: A usted estimado. Más luego edito mi respuesta y lo explico a más detalle, lo hice desde mi celular jeje

Comment: si amigo muchisimas gracias.

Comment: Listo estimado, espero que haya quedado más claro, saludos.

Answer (score 2):

*(En respuesta al error Property 'success' does not exist on type 'Object')*

TypeScript es un superconjunto de Javascript, al que le agrega tipado estatico y objetos basados en clases y aunque en general son casi el mismo lenguaje TypeScript **tiene muchas mas restricciones que tiene sus ventajas y sus desventajas**, digamos que en JS tenemos mas libertad de hacer asignaciones arbitrarias sin errores en cambio en TS debemos aclarar constantemente los tipos de datos. Aunque parezca una desventaja un tipado estatico es menos vulnerable a errores.
Una solucion es crear una interfaz e implementarla en el objeto:

```
interface objTemplate{ // interfaz que define una "maqueta" de tu objeto
  success : Number; // solo definimos el nombre de la propiedad y el tipo
}

let data : objTemplate = { // objeto creado en base a la interfaz
  success : 194
}

let number = data.success; // ya no tirara error, porque el compilador ahora reconoce la variable success, gracias a la interfaz
console.log(typeof(number))
```

solo quería agregar eso si te servía, hay programadores que piensan que el tipado dinámico (tipo JS) es mejor que el estático de TS y hay gente que piensa lo contrario, para mí son dos métodos y tienen sus ventajas y sus desventajas. Así que lo mejor sería que borres la etiqueta JavaScript por las restricciones mencionadas. Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias por la información, amigo, se agradece la información y tu tiempo.